# How do I transfer files from the guest system to the host system?

Tags: 11.04, virtualbox

Hello Id like to run a Windows 7 Virtual Machine on my Ubuntu 11.04.
But is there a solution to transfer files from the VM to the hostsystem (in my case ubuntu 11.04).

I would use the VM for converting some files. Then I would like to copy them to my HDD on (ubuntu 11.04). Is this possible ?

Comment: You can use Virtualbox and create a shared folder for the virtual machine and your host.

Answer (score 1):

A Shared Folder in VirtualBox would be the easiest way to go, in my opinion. To the Windows guest the folder would appear a a network share and can even be mapped to a network drive.

Comment: Manual pages for Shared Folders: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to share files from your host system with the guest system.

- VirtualBox shared folders
- Samba share
- Run a HTTP server (one way unless you're using a dynamic language)
- Run a FTP server

You share files the same way as if the guest system was another computer in the network.